# Why is Wireshark reporting that my HTTP/1.1 connection is issuing a HTTP/2 RESET_STREAM command?

Tags: wireshark, http2

I have a client and server that are both using HTTP/1.1.
After a handful of HTTP/1.1 exchanges, Wireshark identifies a single HTTP2 command of type RESET_STREAM (from the client) having an error code of "Unknown".

I am suspicious that Wireshark is erroneously parsing this HTTP2 "message" from the binary data payload of my HTTP/1.1 connection (as controlled by a Content-Length header).  However, the fact that my HTTP/1.1 session does not progress as expected in this particular environment, has caused me to wonder what is going on?

Any ideas or comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug filed against Wireshark ([Bug 10335 - 1.12.0 does not dissect HTTP correctly](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10335) ) describes:

> Both the client and the server listed their HTTP version as 1.1 in their http.request.version headers.
>
> ...
>
> 290 packets are listed as HTTP2

which suggests a known problem with the heuristic detection of HTTP/2 frames. A partial fix introduces a way to disable HTTP/2 detection.